# Finding point in image

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to build a neural network that could put a point in 300x300 image. I know where the point should be in images. Where should I look into to find this type of tenser flow tutorials because all I see is image classifiers? It sounds simple to me but I can't find any tutorials. I know where the point should be and I want to train a neural network to output the same point position in 300x300 black&white image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
It's not clear what you have for input and what you want as a result.  What you're trying to do is likely a regression problem rather than classification -- but we don't have enough information to tell.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually easier than classification, as you have a continuous error function.

The big problem seems to be that you don't understand the fundamentals. A neural network is trained by defining its shape, randomly initializing it, calculating the outcome for a given input (forward pass), calculating the difference between actual and desired output (error), and then back-propagating that error (backward pass).

In your case, the output is an X-Y pair, so two output nodes. The error is simply the dX,dY difference between your point and the predicted point.